# c# создание десктопной файлообменника в локальной сети

Tags: c#

уважаемые люди, у меня есть локальный сеть, хочу создать файлообменник(аналог FlylinkDC) на 40 человек допустим, с помощью с# winform(еще socket хочу использовать), mysql. актуально ли данный момент такая реализация ? для меня важно реализовать именно десткоп версию, вместе WEB. посоветуйте пожалуйста есть ли исходники или примеры реализации такого проекта. ниже привел образный макет[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чём смысл? От DC++ почти везде давно отказались, поскольку там шарят не пойми что не пойми как. Файлы можно обзывать как угодно и пойди пойми, что там на самом деле. В торрентах хотя бы есть модерируемая борда с описаниями файлов обычно и там хоть понимаешь, что качаешь. Ну и каналы стали гораздо лучше, не ADSL какой, можно прямо каталоги где-то открывать, да на них всё выкладывать.

Comment: нет, я в пример привел, а так локальный файлообменник с чатом хочу сделать, с помощью сокета,  просто нужны советы как реализовать , макет сделал на winform , теперь самое интересное ) написать серверную и клиентскую часть

Comment: через Wamp сервер , в базу  все пользователи сети подключаются,  я хочу создать аккаунт для каждого пользователя под определенный IP адрес, чтобы один пользователь сети через форму мог отправить файл или сообщение другому пользователю сети

Comment: А почему не использовать `Telegram` какой-нибудь, сделать там группу, в которую можно добавлять по приглашениям. Если с целью потренироваться - ну, разбирайтесь, но задача проще решается готовыми средствами )

Comment: ну задача очень интересная , тем более у меня Датагрид  Mysql по локалке работает , добавляет удаляет , теперь хочу чтобы юзери могли друг другу отправлять файлы по TCP

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вашего вопроса. Как сделать чат - миллион и более примеров в гугле. Как отправлять файл - еще больше. Для чата обычные сокеты уже не актуально. Смотрите в сторону SignalR. Да и для передачи файлов он подойдет, только не больших.

Comment: для десктоп AP подойдет SignalR ?,  мне нужно реализовать десткоп версию вместе WEB

Comment: свыше добавил макет для прояснения проблемы